# Php foreach loop for table output

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to create a code to do the following:

For each item, display the ingredients under it

Here is my code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,
        "SELECT * 
                FROM recipe_ingredients ri 
                JOIN recipes r 
                ON ri.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
                JOIN measurement_units mu
                ON ri.measurement_id = mu.measurement_id
                JOIN measurementqty mq
                ON ri.measurement_qty_id = mq.measurementqty_id
                JOIN ingredients i
                ON ri.ingredient_id = i.ingredient_id;
                ");
    echo "<table align='center' border='1' style='width: 600px'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Recipe Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Ingredients</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><center>" . $row['recipe_name'] . "</center></td>";
        echo "<td><center>" . $row['qty_amount'] . " " . $row['measurement_description'] . " " . $row['ingredient_name'] ." </center></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

It is currently outputting a table that looks like this:

| Recipe Name | Ingredients |
| --- | --- |
| Vanilla Cupcakes | 200 grams sugar |
| Vanilla Cupcakes | 300 grams flour |
| Vanilla Cupcakes | 1 tbsp vanilla |

Here is what I want my results to look like instead

| Vanilla Cupcakes |
| --- |
| 200 grams sugar |
| 300 grams flour |
| 300 grams flour |
| 1 tbsp vanilla |
| 50 grams butter |

I am still playing around with foreach loops but cannot get any to work.

Comment: Are you wanting to make a separate table for each recipe?